# Redirect posts to sub domain except pages

Tags: posts, redirect, subdomains

We have a WordPress site, which contains posts and pages. Now we moved posts into sub domain but we kept pages into root domain. Only Posts has `.html` extension and there is no difference in the URL for Posts & Pages.

Sample Post: `www.mydomain.com/sample-posts.html` need to redirect with `blog.mydomain.com/sample-posts.html`.

Sample Page: `www.mydomain.com/sample-pages`

How to redirect only posts in to sub domain?

Comment: It might matter _how_ did you do it? Is this still one WP installation?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this per server configuration. Here is an example for the `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ http://blog.example.com/$1.html [L,R=301]
```

You could do this in a WordPress plugin too. Untested suggestion:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_77279_redirect' );

function wpse_77279_redirect()
{
    if ( is_single() 
        and 'blog.example.com' !== $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] 
        and 'post' === get_post_type() 
    )
    {
        wp_redirect( 'blog.example.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
        exit;
    }
}
```